# CSS background image won't scale

Tags: css

I'm trying to learn html and css. Right now I'm trying to make a background image fill the browser window no matter the size. 
I've googled it 100 times and every page pretty much says the same thing. So I copied the code and it isn't working for me. When I set my browser to a smaller size, the background image repeats itself. Which I don't want I just want it to fill the window. 
Here's my css.

```
html {
background-image:url(background.jpg);
background-size: 100%;
background-image: no-repeat-y; }
```

Before I did 100%, I tried using cover instead and that didn't work either. The image is fullscreen when the window is maximized but when I resize it the image will repeat.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/  this might help you

Comment: use body {...} instead of html {...}

Comment: and background-image: no-repeat... is wrong... It must be "background-repeat" ...

Comment: I fixed the no repeat, and now the image will just cut off and there is white space underneath. I copied the css NYCBilly gave me and the image still won't scale when I shrink the browser window.

**Nevermind. For some reason I missed the other 100% he typed. It is working now.

Comment: Ignore that, glad it worked... :)

Comment: use that:
body {
background-image: url("background.jpg");
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vh;
}

Comment: I see you're new (1 post) - don't forget to select ANSWERED please... That's one reason this website is so fun for us who like to help... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scale, the CSS you want to scale needs to be inside a container itself, namely BODY inside the HTML container; try this:

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-image:url(background.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `background-size cover` will do the job:

```
html { 
  background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a height of 100% to the parent div `<body>` so that any child div with a height: 100%; will take the height of it's parent div. Here's an example:

Wrap your content in a parent div like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapMeTight">
      ....Your page content....
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And add this to your css:

```
html, body    {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapMeTight   {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url (/img.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { background-image: url("background.jpg"); background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 100vh; width: 100vh; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```